# Tensor product and quotients of it

Tags: banach-algebras, tensor-products

Let $A,B$ be Banach algebras, and $I$ be a closed two sided ideal of $A$ and 
 $J$ be a closed two sided ideal of $B$. Is the relation $A\hat{\otimes}B/I\hat{\otimes}J\cong A/I\hat{\otimes}B/J$ true?(I mean topological isomorphism and projective tensor product). If it isn't true in general, is there conditions that make it true?

Comment: This is not even true for finite-dimensional algebras $A$ and $B$.  Not even for finite-dimensional vector spaces with vector subspaces.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because: (1) if we consider the specific question that was asked, then there are easy finite-dimensional counterexamples; (2) I do not believe in encouraging questions of the form "please provide some extra conditions so that the result I want to be true becomes true", especially when no indication is given that the OP has made proper efforts to investigate such extra conditions